# Where can i find a dataset of handwritten broken numbers or floats or digits?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, dataset, ocr

I m looking for **DATASET of HANDWRITTEN BROKEN NUMBERS or floats or digits** which means for example a teacher s handwritten mark of students or anything like these images below
**thank you in advance**
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRFKA.png)

Comment: If you search for datasets, www.Kaggle.com is the place to search for . https://www.kaggle.com/c/digit-recognizer/data

Comment: Your AI will not be able to predict 100% accuracy most of the time so you need to expect some misses.You can simply alter the datasets posted or improve your model by fixing possible overfit, choosing a more robust structure, do some additional image preprocessing (morphological). If all those datasets are still not what you want, You're stuck with making your own dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google recently launched a Dataset search engine, you can type in `handwritten digits` and check all the options ([link to that exact query](https://datasetsearch.research.google.com/search?query=handwritten%20digits)).

Some options available (besides the well known MNIST):

- Pen-Based Recognition of Handwritten Digits ([link](https://data.world/uci/pen-based-recognition-of-handwritten-digits))
- Semeion Handwritten Digits ([link](https://data.world/uci/semeion-handwritten-digit))

Comment: i need a dataset with noise just like that example , when you see for example the 08,5 the " 8 " has noise that my model cant identify it correctly :/

Answer (score 0):

You could use the MNIST dataset and then add some noise to it. Maybe openCV has some functions for you, like erode, dilate. Maybe some of [Morphological Transformations](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html) could help you (`Closing`, for an example)

Comment: i need a dataset with noise just like that example , when you see for example the 08,5 the " 8 " has noise that my model cant identify it correctly :/

Comment: @Adem Yoessed Where is the problem with generating your own noise? What do you want to accomplish with that? if you just want to increase your accuracy you can get that by using Data-Augmentation on already existing training data.

Comment: i think the right option for me now is to correct ( cancel or remove the noise from my data ) my data
well thanks a lot for your time

Answer (score 0):

You can start with the most popular handwritten digits dataset.

Here's a link to the website from where you can download.

http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/

http://cis.jhu.edu/~sachin/digit/digit.html

Comment: i need a dataset with noise just like that example , when you see for example the 08,5 the " 8 " has noise that my model cant identify it correctly :/